# Slide to next page will proportionally move something else

Tags: android, slider, android-viewpager, slideshow

I saw something fancy about slide pages, such as picture below.

If I slides from this page to next, on top of page, there is something moving proportionally, e.g, I can see the top rectangular are sliding gradually with page moving, I don't know how to achieve this. can anyone else tell me how to impl this?

I can use ViewPager to achieve sliding, but not know how to move something else like that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there are already have many implementation for this effect, the most famous one is JakeWharton's [viewpagerindicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/). i had achieved this as well, you can check my [project](https://github.com/vince-styling/traversaless-viewpager-android) for a straightforward example.

Comment: That small indicator is not what I refer. I saw the rectangular box moving, that box will fit the Tab title, such as Tab2.

Comment: i think you wanna the Tab move together while switching pages, according my answer's samples, you can draw your rectangle yourself. there haven't a sample that fully match your desired, but they would give you a inspire to fulfill your desired.